# How to connect LUIS to a simple web application without Azure or the MS Bot framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, model-view-controller, azure-language-understanding

I want to know how to integrate LUIS to a simple web application without Azure or MS bot framework. Every resource I find is either using the emulator or Azure or the MS bot framework. I just want to play around and not use so many services. I solely want to work with LUIS and its intents and entities in a web application using C#.

Comment: so what's stopping you, you can easily use the [endpoint API](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5819c76f40a6350ce09de1ac/operations/5819c77140a63516d81aee78) to query LUIS

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **LuisRuntimeAPI**

[Here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/Cognitive-Services-LUIS-Console-Application/blob/master/Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.LUIS.Sample/Program.cs) is a console application example:

```cs
Console.WriteLine("Enter the text to recognize:");
string input = Console.ReadLine().Trim();

if (input.ToLower() == "exit")
{
    // Close application if user types "exit"
    break;
}
else
{
    if (input.Length > 0)
    {
        // Create client with SuscriptionKey and AzureRegion
        var client = new LuisRuntimeAPI(new ApiKeyServiceClientCredentials(SubscriptionKey))
        {
            AzureRegion = AzureRegion
        };

        // Predict
        var result = await client.Prediction.ResolveAsync(ApplicationId, input);

        // Print result
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result, Formatting.Indented);
        Console.WriteLine(json);
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: More examples here: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-language-understanding/tree/master/examples

Answer (score 0):

LUIS Provide API endpoints with a details documentation, with that you can create a simple app without using Azure or .net
you can choose any language you want.

1. LUIS provides an API Endpoint to get prediction results
2. LUIS provides various endpoints to train new utterances/intent.

**With Luis, you can train an utterance from API itself and also you can mark words as entities.**
 check the LUIS Documentation [here](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/), in case you are interested to use LUIS with NodeJS here, is the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-get-started-node-get-intent)